# What are the squares in $\mathbb{R}((X))$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, formal-power-series

My attempt:

For an indeterminate $Y$ we know there exists $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$ with
$$\sqrt{1+Y} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k Y^k.$$
If we would take an element $f(X) = \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} b_k X^k \in \mathbb{R}((X)$ for $b_k \in 
\mathbb{R}$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ we could substitute $f(X)$ for $Y$. Then we would get
$$ \sqrt{1+f(X)} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k \left( f(X) \right)^k. $$
But the last sum is not an element in $\mathbb{R}((X))$ in general. If we would take $f(X) = X^{-1}$ for example then there exists no finite $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $c_k \in \mathbb{R}$ with
$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k \left( X^{-1} \right)^k = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} c_k X^k$.
For $m \geq 0 $ otherwise we would get an element in $\mathbb{R}((X))$. But this would imply (for $f(X) = -1 + X$) that X is a square in $\mathbb{R}((X))$ which is false. Thus I think I cannot substitute simply $f(X)$ for $Y$. So my questions are:

- Why is this substitution not allowed?
- How can you find all the squares in $\mathbb{R}((X))$?

Comment: You may want to look at the answers here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1675244/19006 and try to figure out what changes when working over $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing mysterious.
$$\Bbb{R}((X))^\times = X^\Bbb{Z}\ \times\ \Bbb{R}^\times\times\ 1\!+\!X \Bbb{R}[[X]]$$
$$\Bbb{R}((X))^{\times 2} = X^{2\Bbb{Z}}\ \times\ \Bbb{R}_{>0}\times\ 1\!+\!X \Bbb{R}[[X]]$$
In other words, an element of $\Bbb{R}((X))^\times$ is a square if and only if it leading term is of the form $a_kX^k$ where $k$ is an even integer (possibly negative) and $a_k>0$.

Comment: And about "substitutions", see proposition 7.15 of http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~dgwagner/co430I.pdf

Comment: With $\times$ you mean the cartesian product? So an element on the right side of the equation would be $(X^2, 3, 1) + 0$. But I cannot see how this is an element in $\mathbb{R}((X))$.

Comment: @Valentin Yes, direct product of groups.

Comment: @reuns How do you identify an element in $\mathbb{R}((X))^\times$ with an element in $X^\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}^\times \times 1 + X \mathbb{R}[[X]]$ for example?

Comment: Just divide your Laurent series by $a_n X^n$ where $n$ is the least integer such that $a_n\ne 0$ @Valentin

Comment: Oh allright. I read it like $(X^\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}^\times \times 1) + X \mathbb{R}[[X]]$ but it actually is $X^\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}^\times \times (1 + X \mathbb{R}[[X]])$. Thank you!